# Setting all NA to blank in r Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I've been successful most of the time but in one instance the following code, throws error.

**Error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format**

```
current[is.na(current)] = ""
```

The following works. But how do I avoid writing 3 times?

```
isnaColumns <- sapply(current, is.character)
current[,isnaColumns] <- lapply(current[,isnaColumns], function(z) replace(z, is.na(z), ""))

isnaColumns <- sapply(current, is.numeric)
current[,isnaColumns] <- lapply(current[,isnaColumns], function(z) replace(z, is.na(z), "" ))

isnaColumns <- sapply(current, is.logical)
current[,isnaColumns] <- lapply(current[,isnaColumns], function(z) replace(z, is.na(z), "" ))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please post this as answer and I can vote for the same.

Comment: FYI, replacing `NA` in a numeric column with the empty string `""` is ... destructive. No more numbers, only strings. I suggest that even if that is what you really want, then you should be declarative about it and pre-coerce to strings (with `as.character`) before you get to this step.

Comment: Thanks. That is a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.

Comment: I think a lot of people stress unnecessarily about having `NA` in their frames, and want to cleanup the way it is displayed on the console during exploration. To this, I tend to reply: showing data on the console is one thing, showing it in a report is completely different. I prefer *"just-in-time conversion"*, meaning that if you don't want to show `NA`s in a report, then convert them from `NA` to something else immediately before printing a summary table. Most functions that deal with numbers/times accept `na.rm=` or similar, so working with `NA`s is often simple.

Answer (score 2):

I think an even better approach is to only update columns that make sense to update, as in `character` and possibly `factor`. The former is as simple as

```r
ischr <- sapply(current, is.character)
current[,ischr] <- lapply(current[,ischr], function(z) replace(z, is.na(z), ""))
```

(Apologies for the previous code that was exploding incorrectly ...)

Testing with large-ish data:

```r
n <- 1e7 # 10,000,000
set.seed(42) # R-4.0.2
current <- data.frame(
  int=sample(1000, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  chr1=sample(letters, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  chr2=sample(LETTERS, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  chr3=sample(letters, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  chr4=sample(LETTERS, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  chr5=sample(letters, size=n, replace=TRUE),
  chr6=sample(LETTERS, size=n, replace=TRUE)
)
ischr <- sapply(current, is.character)
ischr
#   int  chr1  chr2  chr3  chr4  chr5  chr6 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE 
current[,ischr] <- lapply(current[,ischr], function(z) replace(z, sample(n, size=n/10), NA))
head(current)
#   int chr1 chr2 chr3 chr4 chr5 chr6
# 1 561    y    Z    m    D    y    P
# 2 997    l    D    q <NA>    c    C
# 3 321    z    Q    a    E <NA>    H
# 4 153    n    K <NA>    C    h    P
# 5  74 <NA>    I    t    S    y    N
# 6 228    e    C    s    Z    q    L
system.time({
  current[,ischr] <- lapply(current[,ischr], function(z) replace(z, is.na(z), ""))
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.39    0.06    0.45 
head(current)
#   int chr1 chr2 chr3 chr4 chr5 chr6
# 1 561    y    Z    m    D    y    P
# 2 997    l    D    q         c    C
# 3 321    z    Q    a    E         H
# 4 153    n    K         C    h    P
# 5  74         I    t    S    y    N
# 6 228    e    C    s    Z    q    L
```

Comment: Ah good point - I took `current` to be a vector (missing the title of the post).

Comment: Only problem with this solution is that, it hangs the entire system. The dataframe is huge. Thus, replacing with this method, pretty much hangs the system.

Comment: If you're dealing with a large dataset, then you might consider `data.table`: it's more memory-efficient and therefore typically faster than base R and `dplyr`, often at the expense of another R-dialect (and some other nuances). My day-to-day data are usually only 2-3M rows and I use `data.table`, so I've not seen any performance issues.

Comment: Hrmmmm ... seems like `replace` isn't working the same on a sample I just tested ... stby

Comment: Sorry about that, see my edit ... not sure exactly why the first version worked initially ... (actually, I do know why ... b/c I only tested on a couple of columns, where `is.na(...)` would indeed return only one column's worth. With multiple columns, it was not returning a `list`-like structure that is required for `Map`. Again, my apologies.)

Comment: Works well. Only constraint is that I've to use 3 separate commands to get the same done. Is there a way to get it done in one single go?

Comment: Wait, I just saw this ... you want to find all `NA` in your numeric/logical columns and, if any are found, change the entire column to strings? Because that's what you're doing: the moment you change one non-`character` to the empty string `""`, you change the entire column to `character`, losing all of your numeric/logical properties (such as the ability to do math).